# Elastic: refer to a calculated metric value inside the filter of another aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm wondering if it is possible to refer to a computed metric value (I'm calculating the median of price in my documents) inside the filter of another aggregation.

Specifically, I know that I can calculate the median like this:

```
"aggs":{
  "median": { 
    "percentiles" : {
      "field" : "price",
      "percents": [50]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

But now can I refer to this value inside another aggregation, like this:

```
"aggs": {
  "exact": {
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "range": {
              "price": {
                "gte": 1000,
                "lte": median
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    } 
  },
  ...
}
```

Please let me know if I can provide any more details. I've been reading Elastic docs all day and it seems like I could do it with some combination of scripting and pipeline aggregations, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Thanks in advance.